# Mathematical methods applied to Earth science?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we welcome questions about the interpretation of mathematical tools used in Earth Science?

For example, I asked a question related to [the interpretation of the mathematics of remote sounding](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2136/6).

Is this question suitable for Earth Science, or better asked elsewhere?

Comment: Hmm, in this case [Stats.SE] would probably be the best other candidate.

Comment: I'm not sure about whether it's on-topic here or not, but I agree that statistics.SE would be more likely to give useful answers!

Answer (score 10):

The nature of earth sciences is interdisciplinary, and, perhaps because many mathematical conventions are repeated through the Earth sciences this would indeed be the best place to get those questions answered.

What is important is to provide both the question and answer in an Earth Science context, there is a difference, for example to the following questions:

What is a Fourier transform ?

and

Why do seismologists use Fourier transforms?

The answer to both questions will undoubtedly touch into the pure mathematical nature of Fourier, but the second applies the pure mathematics.

So on this question, nuance is required.

Comment: Yes I agree. I didn't feel strongly enough to vote to close gerrit's post, but it did seem off-topic as written.